# Как сохранить данные из onResponse RETROFIT

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Не могу придумать как получить данные из `onResponse()`:

```
public class ControllerPost implements Callback<RegistrationResponse> {

public Context context;

static final String BASE_URL = "http://busboosted.000webhostapp.com/";

public void start(final Context context, String login, String password) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    this.context = context;

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();



    Api gerritAPI = retrofit.create(Api.class);


    RegistrationBody reg = new RegistrationBody(login, password); 
   // System.out.println("<========================>");
   // System.out.println(gson.toJson(reg));
   // System.out.println("<========================>");

    RequestBody requestBody = 
 RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), gson.toJson(reg));



   Call<RegistrationResponse> call = gerritAPI.getResult(requestBody);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<RegistrationResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<RegistrationResponse> call, 
Response<RegistrationResponse> response) {
            RegistrationResponse res = response.body();
//здесь
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<RegistrationResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            System.out.println(t.getMessage().toString());
        }
    });




}


@Override
public void onResponse(Call<RegistrationResponse> call, Response<RegistrationResponse> response) {
    RegistrationResponse res = response.body();

    System.out.println(res.result);

}

@Override
public void onFailure(Call<RegistrationResponse> call, Throwable t) {

    System.out.println(t.getMessage().toString());
}


}
```

А запускаю отсюда:

```
 View.OnClickListener oclLoginIp = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            ControllerPost controllet = new ControllerPost();
            controllet.start(context,edit1.getText().toString(), 
edit2.getText().toString());

//и нужно сюда возвратить результат


        }
    };
```

Comment: Именно туда не получится, так как запрос асинхронный.

Comment: @woesss, а что поменять нужно

Answer (score 1):

Создайте Ваш `Callback<RegistrationResponse>` в вызывающем классе и передайте в `ControllerPost` через `start` четвёртым параметром. Тогда Вы получите результат в вызвавшем классе

```
View.OnClickListener oclLoginIp = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        ControllerPost controllet = new ControllerPost();
        controllet.start(context, edit1.getText().toString(), 
                         edit2.getText().toString(),
                         new Callback<RegistrationResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<RegistrationResponse> call, 
                                   Response<RegistrationResponse> response) {
                RegistrationResponse res = response.body();
                // вот здесь и используем дальше
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<RegistrationResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                System.out.println(t.getMessage().toString());
            }
         });
```

---

В `ControllerPost` :

```
public void start(final Context context,
                  String login,
                  String password,
                  Callback<RegistrationResponse> callback) {
    // some code
    call.enqueue(callback);
    // some code
}
```

Comment: спсибо, попробую.